# Mysql Warning: aborted connection and got an error reading communication package

Tags: mysql

I have a client device sending data to mysql DB and receiving some data from DB every minutes. I have been getting the following warning messages.  I have been searching for a proper solution for this. I am closing the db connection properly. But I still couldn't find a proper solution. any suggestions would be helpful.

```
2019-08-27 10:35:26 32 [Warning] Aborted connection 32 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'root' host: '192.168.xx.xxx' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2019-08-27 10:35:26 35 [Warning] Aborted connection 35 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'root' host: '192.168.xx.xxx' (Got an error reading communication packets)

2019-08-27 10:36:26 36 [Warning] Aborted connection 36 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'root' host: '192.168.xx.xxx' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2019-08-27 10:36:26 39 [Warning] Aborted connection 39 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'root' host: '192.168.xx.xxx' (Got an error reading communication packets)


//and it goes on
//192.168.xx.xxx is the IP of the device
//why it says db: 'unconnected' even though my db name is myData
```

Comment: What was the outcome of this? Can you share your findings and the fix?
Was this a security related issue or code?